# MySQL DELETE INSERT instead of UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Is there a way to use delete->insert instead of update with using fields from the first record?

Example with update:

```
TABLE
---------
ID (int)  | VAL_1(VARCHAR)  | VAL_2 (VARCHAR)
```

Message 1:  `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (1, "first message", "some val");`

Message 2:  `UPDATE TABLE SET ID=2 WHERE ID=1`

Instead, I need to delete the first record and insert a new one.  Is there a way to use a message like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(2, VAL_1 from RECORD WHERE ID=1, VAL_2 from the record WHERE ID=1);
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: no. insert/delete cannot be chained in a single query. you could try using a trigger or a stored proc.

Comment: You could insert into a temporary table, delete the rows, then merge the temporary into your main table.

Comment: Go with a pl/sql trigger..

Comment: What about the `REPLACE INTO` command?

Comment: how do triggers work?  example?

Comment: REPLACE INTO won't maintain the original values.  I only want to change the ID, so what would the full statement look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, val_1, val_2) 
SELECT id+1, val_1, val_2 
FROM table WHERE id =1;

DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

like tadman said, i think REPLACE would accomplish this better:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Comment: Sadly REPLACE does not work in this case, replace would simply overwrite the row with key number 2 (if it already exists), leaving the one with value 1 (which the OP really wants to delete) in place, and therefore creating a duplicate entry. Eg.: `REPLACE INTO table (id, ...) SELECT id+1, ... FROM table WHERE id=1` would translate into `DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=2; INSERT INTO table (id, ...) SELECT id+1, ... FROM table WHERE id=1;`